# How to read a string from file and split to get a data string?

Tags: java, file, split

I need to get a String from a file. I know how to read the whole file using BufferedReader and I know how to get a value like "Integer: 5" I can get the Integer 5 from that but I don't know how to do the same thing and get a whole String from it. What I mean is, lets say I have "Data: This is a data String" wrote in a file. I need to know how to read the string and get the "This is a data String" from it.

```
EDIT: This is the text in the file that I need to read 
https://pastebin.com/gc9vFLGD

and this is the code that I have tried.

https://pastebin.com/uDfasn7i
```

Comment: try to use regex.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm pretty new to java.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Please show us a snippet of what you have tried and where you are facing a problem.  The exact format of the String from the file would also be helpful.

Comment: I need something to get the String between two characters. So, if I have "[Oh hello]" is there a way to get the text between the two []?

Comment: This is the text in the file that I need to read https://pastebin.com/gc9vFLGD

and this is the code that I have tried.

   https://pastebin.com/uDfasn7i

Comment: Post the code code here. The curly braces ahead of the edit field are for code formatting. Have you seen other questions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks preparation, links to code instead of presenting it here.

Comment: Calm down man, Jeez.

Comment: For basic functionality you could just try with good old fashioned indexOf and substring

Comment: @userunknown Agreed.  Coda Plays, there is still time to update your question before it is closed

Comment: And what exactly needs updating? I'm very new to StackOverflow and do not recall the requirements needed to post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @msagala25 is right with his comment, one of the easiest things to do is to use a **[Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)** (RegEx) to retrieve 1 (or possibly more) specific sub-strings from a String when used in conjunction with Java's **java.util.regex** **[Pattern and Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)** Classes.

Below is a method (**getBetween()**) to demonstrate how you can retrieve pretty much whatever sub-string you want out of a String providing you supply Left and Right String Tags (so to speak). Let's take the second line within your text file:

```
String fileLine = "[Slot Number: 0, Item ID: 399, Item Data: ItemStack{NETHER_STAR x 1, "
                + "UNSPECIFIC_META:{meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, display-name=§6Kit Selector, "
                + "lore=[§eUse this to, §eselect a kit!]}}]";
```

If we want the value of **`399`** in string for the **`Item ID:`** element our Left String Tag would be: **`"Item ID:"`** and our Right String Tag would be: **`","`**, for example:

```
String leftTag = "Item ID:";
String rightTag = ",";
String[] data = getBetween(a, leftTag, rightTag);
System.out.println("The Item ID in String is: " + data[0]);
```

The console window will display: **`The Item ID in String is: 399`**

The **getBetween()** method returns a Single Dimensional String Array for the sole reason that the supplied **fileLine** string could possibly contain more than one set of Left and Right String Tags. The method could easily be enhanced to only return a specific instance or specific instances of what is between the supplied Left and Right String Tags. Currently you would need to iterate through the array to get the instance you require if you know there is more than one. In the **fileLine** string provided above, we know there is only one Left String Tag instance of **"Item ID:"** which contains a Right String Tag of **","** within the supplied **fileLine** string therefore the example code above simply uses **index 0** of the array to display the desired content.

This method by default trims any leading or trailing tabs and or white-spaces from the results before it is placed into the returned 1D String Array. This can be optionally turned off through the **trimFound** optional parameter by supplying  a boolean false. Ignoring Letter Case (default is false) can also be changed can also be applied supplying boolean true to the **ignoreLetterCase** optional parameter (read the supplied comments section).

Here is the **getBetween()** method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves any string data located between the supplied string leftString
 * parameter and the supplied string rightString parameter.<br><br>
 *
 * This method will return all instances of a substring located between the
 * supplied Left String and the supplied Right String which may be found
 * within the supplied Input String.<br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to look for substring(s) in.
 *
 * @param leftString (String) What may be to the Left side of the substring we want 
 * within the main input string.
 *
 * @param rightString (String) What may be to the Right side of the substring we want 
 * within the main input string..
 *
 * @param options (Optional - Boolean - 2 Parameters):<pre>
 *
 *      ignoreLetterCase    - Default is false. This option works against the
 *                            string supplied within the letString parameter
 *                            and the string supplied within the rightString
 *                            parameter. If set to true then letter case is
 *                            ignored when searching for strings supplied in
 *                            these two parameters. If left at default false
 *                            then letter case is not ignored.
 *
 *      trimFound           - Default is true. By default this method will trim
 *                            off leading and trailing white-spaces from found
 *                            sub-string items. General sentences which obviously
 *                            contain spaces will almost always give you a white-
 *                            space within an extracted sub-string. By setting
 *                            this parameter to false, leading and trailing white-
 *                            spaces are not trimmed off before they are placed
 *                            into the returned Array.</pre>
 *
 * @return (1D String Array) Returns a Single Dimensional String Array
 * containing all the sub-strings found within the supplied Input String
 * which are between the supplied Left String and supplied Right String.
 * You can shorten this method up a little by returning a List&lt;String&gt;  
 * ArrayList and removing the 'List to 1D Array' conversion code at the end 
 * of this method. This method initially stores its findings within a List 
 * object anyways.
 */
public static String[] getBetween(String inputString, String leftString, String rightString, boolean... options) {
    // Return nothing if nothing was supplied.
    if (inputString.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }

    // Prepare optional parameters if any supplied.
    // If none supplied then use Defaults...
    boolean ignoreCase = false; // Default.
    boolean trimFound = true;   // Default.
    if (options.length > 0) {
        if (options.length >= 1) {
            ignoreCase = options[0];
        }
        if (options.length >= 2) {
            trimFound = options[1];
        }
    }

    // Remove any ASCII control characters from the
    // supplied string (if they exist).
    String modString = inputString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");

    // Establish a List String Array Object to hold
    // our found substrings between the supplied Left
    // String and supplied Right String.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    /// Use Pattern Matching to locate our possible
    // substrings within the supplied Input String.
    String regEx = Pattern.quote(leftString) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(rightString);
    if (ignoreCase) { regEx = "(?i)" + regEx; }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(modString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        // Add the found substrings into the List.
        String found = matcher.group(1);
        if (trimFound) {
            found = found.trim();
        }
        list.add(found);
    }

    String[] res;
    // Convert the ArrayList to a 1D String Array.
    // If the List contains something then convert
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        res = new String[list.size()];
        res = list.toArray(res);
    } // Otherwise return Null.
    else {
        res = null;
    }
    // Return the String Array.
    return res;
}
```

As mentioned earlier, Pattern/Matcher is used to to retrieve the required sub-strings with the use of a Regular Expression. There are two different expressions used depending upon whether or not Letter Case is to be ignored. Here are the explanations for each expression:

> **If Letter Case Is Not Ignored:**  "\\Q" + leftStringTag +
>   "\\E(.*?)\\Q" + rightStringTag + "\\E"

[image]

> **If Letter Case Is Ignored:**  "(?i)\\Q" + leftStringTag +
>   "\\E(.*?)\\Q" + rightStringTag + "\\E"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not simple to use only split and your code also incorrect.

1.Firstly, split with "," you have the pattern of data look like
dataName: dataValue

2.Next, if you split you data with ":" , you will face problem that dataValue also may contains ":"
and split will not work as expected. (I suggest split with the first character ':')

3.Inside your dataValue also contain data with pattern AA:BB -> continue define rule but Split in some cases can not solve your rule.
I show you simple example to get data use both Pattern and String  (in step 2).

```
    public static void main (String ...args){
    String input = "Data: Parent data: Child data";
    String regex = "[:]"; // regular expression
    // Using Pattern class
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String output1 = pattern.split(input,2)[1];
    // Using String class
    String output2 = input.split(regex,2)[1];
    System.out.println(output1);
    System.out.println(output2);
  }
```

If you want more data in step 3, let learn about regex (regular expression) and see java doc of Pattern to understand how it is work. After that define your own rule to parse raw data. Maybe it hard but regex is very powerful to do many tasks. At least show your research and question again if has any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question...

I hope that, that file is not actually going to look like that, cause that is a mess waiting to happen... make it individual lines, and than use my code... it makes it a WHOLE lot simpler...

Now there are 2 things you should know:

**1.)** You can get the second part of the String using this:

```
String text;
String[] scan=text.split(": ");
String ret=scan[1];
```

What this does is it separates the String containing `:` and than grabs the second part of the String...

**2.)** If you already know text that is going to be in that String you can use this:

```
public static String replaceAllString(String s, String a, String b) {
    s.replace(a, b);
    return s;
}

public static void Example() {
    String text;
    text = replaceAllString(line, knownValue, "");

    //knownValue: is the part of the String you DO NOT want in it...
    //line: is the line from the file
}
```

Now what this does is it instead of splitting the String, it just grabs the String raw, and takes away the known value of it that you DO NOT want in the String (this **will not** edit the line from the file)...

Now if you have to keep it with the file as one big huge mess, than I recommend doing this:

```
public static String[] getInfo() {
    //assuming you have already done the file buffer read...
    String[] sep=line.split(", ");
    return sep;
}

public static String grab(String start) {
    String sep=grabInfo();
    String info="";
    for (String s : sep) {
        if (s.contains(start)) {
            String[] c=s.split(start);
            info=c[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return info;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please look at java.nio package of apache IOUtils which provides straight forward methods to read file line by line. Once you have read a line you need to use a Regex based search to get what you need from that string.

Also I see that you are just reading until you find s particular string , is that the requirement ?

Also  you are not closing the file, thus having a resource leak here as well.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I will fix the File Closing and, I prefer not to use an API. I will also look into Regex. Thanks!